# Effective usages of using/accessing excel files with python

Tags: python, excel, variables, dictionary

(Before i go ahead and ask this question please understand that i have done research but this is just to fill in holes in my information)

I have a standard excel spread sheet .xls that contains one table with the following info in it:
[image: Data_Set_One]

Now what i would like to achieve is to directly translate this .xls file into a data type that can be stored in memory for the python application that im writing to access this information accordingly like a dictionary.

I have read up a fair bit on this but my experience in coding isn't 100% as it has been awhile.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me but I suggest you to check pandas - http://pandas.pydata.org/ http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: My computer corrupted recently so i have lost alot of data and the examples of what i have done. sorry about that, i kinda stopped programming for awhile because of that situation that happened

Comment: @TomRon I reckon this could all be done with just the `csv` module

Comment: Ill look into pandas thanks for that. all i wanted was to take an .xls file and store it in a python type varible for me to do like caculations on or modify in some way.

Answer (score 2):

you can use pandas library, excellent library for excel manipulations.

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_excel("path_to_excel", "sheet_name")
```

data_frame is like a table or matrix that holds your data, you can manipulate this data_frame really easily

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) to loop through the excel file. You can loop through the excel file and create a dictionary, as you suggested.

A better alternative would be [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which reads your excel as a table, called data frame. You can access any cell, row or column from this data frame.

Eg, you have:

```
       X         Y

0   0.213784  0.461443

1   0.703082  0.600445

2   0.111101  0.648624

3   0.101367  0.924729


>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_excel(filename)
>>> df["X"]
0     0.213784
1     0.703082
2     0.111101
3     0.101367
>>> df["Y"]
0     0.461443
1     0.600445
2     0.648624
3     0.924729
>>> df["X"][0]
0.21378370373100195
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you want should be possible with the `csv` module, assuming you convert your `xls` to a `csv` (just save as...).

Like so:

```
import csv

with open('filepath.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['A'], row['B'])
```

`DictReader` takes the first row, and assumes those are the dictionary keys. Then it turns each row into a dictionary where you can access the values using the keys defined in the first row.

If you don't want it to be an actual `dict`, you can just use `csv.reader(f)` which allows you to access the rows using list indexing (the above example would end with `print(row[0], row[1])`).

This all has the nice bonus of being able to use the standard library without any 3rd party imports - so will run on any machine with `Python`.

Comment: Ill give this a go first as it seems fairly straight foward and i think i did use csv ages back